# "save" current page state using javascript

Tags: javascript, uri

What I'm trying to do is have a function create a uri anchor to redraw/rerender/(call it what you want) the entire page

Basically I want to be able to convert any page into a URI scheme so that when I navigate to such a link I get the entire page as is, kinda like saving a webpage. For example if I were to be editing a page and wanted to resume later with all the textareas just the way they are and the forms filled out, or if I wanted to save someones (small) page without having to worry that his site will go down and without having to save files on my computer (I want to use bookmarklets)

Here's what I have so far:

```
html = '<html>' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '</html>';
//html = html.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html;
a.innerHTML = 'click here';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

You see what I'm trying to do.
Ok now the hard part is somehow using a regex to replace all double quotes that are already in double quotes but not ones that aren't.

For example if we create the page

```
<html><body>Testing</body></html>
```

and run the function enough times we're gonna get some issues with the 3rd and on links.

See what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/AvSh3/3/

Comment: I modified your question so hopefully more people who can help will find it/understand it

Comment: I can't wait to see what comes of this. I really don't fully understand what the goal is, but something tells me the results will be cool.

Comment: Do you want to save all of the JavaScript variables on the page as well as the HTML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works when testing on my own page:

```
a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html>' +
    escape(document.documentElement.innerHTML) + '</html>';
a.innerHTML = 'click here';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

I'm guessing that it's just a jsBin/jsFiddle technicality but I have no clue why. Anyway if people want to use this to make bookmarklets heres the link:

....

Well I can't figure out how to make a bookmarklet link in SO, if you want just create a new bookmark with this location:

```
javascript:a=document.createElement("a");a.href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html>"+escape(document.documentElement.innerHTML)+"</html>";a.innerHTML="click here";document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Anyway with this fun tool we can do things like Jon does in the first link here:

http://wundes.com/bookmarklets.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in escape() function:

```
html = escape(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked it into

```
var html = '<html>' + $("html").html() + '</html>';
$('<a></a>').html("click here")
.attr("href", 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape(html))
.appendTo($("body"));
```

Which doesn't display correctly, but when viewing source everything looks correct. Maybe some other special parameter is required?

Comment: actually I'm looking for a non-jQuery answer. I was just using it in jsfiddle because for some reason window.onload wasn't working and I got fed up trying to figure it out. I'm guessing the double quotes need to be escaped when in other double quotes. Unless there's a better way to go about doing this

Comment: @qwe - both appear to work for the simple example.  When I tried in a more complex page (with jQuery, part of Play framework) I got javascript errors and display issues even though source code looks fine.  Not sure what the deal is

Comment: The first link should produce a page with just <html><body>Testing</body></html>. The next link should produce that plus a one level link, the next link should be one level deeper and...we all know how recursion works. The first link in this case produces a page with 3 links, the next produces 1 more link and the next one more.

Comment: @qwe - didn't have that on mine.  I was using `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` to run it.  Actually with yours I get to four and it stays there

Comment: any idea why that is? Better yet, any idea how to fix it? I prefer not to use jQuery