# jQuery - Insert HTML into div, then get first child of inserted HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a problem with a project for a while. Basically, I use `.html()` to load entries into a `div`. It all looks fine, but I tried to get the value of the `:first-child`, and it wouldn't work unless I put the entries directly into the HTML (as in, the source file) -- but I can't do that because the entries need to load dynamically (via JS).

So, I went to look at the page source to see what's up, and nothing showed up in the `div` where my entries were being loaded. I checked Firebug, and it showed that they were inside that `div`. The webpage itself showed that they were inside that `div`. But the page source did not.

Why wouldn't the HTML loaded by jQuery appear in the page source?

## Updated

---

Alright, you guys answered why - so, I guess my real question is "how" to do what I'm trying to do -

The `div` loads several entries into `#inner-wrap` that look somewhat like:

```
<div class="entries">
    <input type="submit" value="1295843239" style="display: none;" class="realtime">
    <span class="time">1295843239:</span>
    <span class="name">Name: </span>
    <span class="message">this is an entry...</span>
</div>
```

How would I select the value of the `input` of the first child of #inner-wrap?

I was using `$("#inner-wrap :first-child .realtime").val()`, but that didn't work when the entries were loaded dynamically. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/UnCpByRY) all the related code, and [here's](http://andrew.x10.mx/freeshout/) the "live" bits of what I have so far. It's nowhere near done, but I need to be able to get the time of the last comment to check for new comments.

Comment: I am trying to add code for you but my javascript and html is blank in my preview, theres just a big grey box..

Comment: I see two of the lines. =/. You could try http://pastebin.com/, and post a link?

Comment: Looking at your code on pastebin, where are you calling the function insert_last_ten()?

Comment: Inside `$(function() { ... }`. Here's all the JS I used on the page - http://pastebin.com/bYwJXVGi. It's on line 38. If it'll help, here's the whole thing. - http://andrew.x10.mx/freeshout/. Still a work in progress, but getting the time of the last shown message is my next step in finishing it. =/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic html will not show in the source when using jQuery unless a postback has occurred. You would need to use a tool such as Firebug to verify the contents or force a postback by adding a form and posting to the same page.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="test.html">
<div id="mycontent">
</div>
</form>

<script>
$('#mycontent').html('Hello World!');
$('#myform').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that, it kept refreshing the page. I tried adding `return false;`, and it kept refreshing the page. Not sure if I'm missing something you were trying to point out, though.

Comment: Post the code that you tried, so I can see why it is refreshing

Answer (score 4):

Stuff added to the DOM after the page is loaded doesn't show up in the "View Source" view because, simply, **it is not in the source of the page.** Use Firebug or the Chrome inspector tool to look at the DOM.

Post the details of your actual problem if you want help with it. It's far more likely that there's something amiss with your code than that there's a jQuery bug, but if you post your stuff it'll be possible for people to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a script that will encode an entire html file based on the actual data. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481348/save-current-page-state-using-javascript) to see how it's done.

Alternatively you can open firebug and save the source that firebug has by right clicking on <html> then save html